# Jump to next tag in pom.xml

Tags: vim, emmet

I'm using [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) which says that it can work in `xml` files but I can't seem to navigate between tags.

Say I have this structure:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google</groupId>
  <artifactId>slides</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/lib.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

How do I jump forwards to the next tag? E.g., with my cursor on the `1` in the version tag how can I move to the second `s` in the next line? (The first `s` of `system`.)

I already tried `<C-y> n` which is the "move to next edit point" but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

> Which my cursor on the first `c` in the second line (of `com` in `com.google`) how can I move to the first `s` in the next line?

```
/s<CR>
```

> How do I jump forwards to the next tag?

Neither Emmet nor Vim have such a feature.

You could add it yourself with a custom function and custom mappings like this:

```
function! JumpToNextTag(dir)
    call search('<[^/][^>]\{-}>.', a:dir == 'backward' ? 'web' : 'we')
endfunction
nnoremap <key> :call JumpToNextTag('forward')<CR>
nnoremap <key> :call JumpToNextTag('backward')<CR>
```

which obviously won't cover every corner case.

> I already tried `<C-y> n` which is the "move to next edit point" but it doesn't seem to work.

["Move to next edit point"](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/master/doc/emmet.txt#L239) doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Also, do you know why emmet doesn't support this? Seems like an extremely useful thing.

Comment: The point of the first part of my answer is to answer your first question. If you don't want the answer, don't ask the question. As for why Emmet doesn't support this, maybe because it's outside of its scope?